# Best practice for allocating memory for use by a function — malloc inside or outside?

Tags: c, malloc

During my experience with C coding, I've seen 2 ways of passing arguments for functions:

1. `malloc` before calling functions
2. `malloc` inside functions (variable is not initialized before calling function)

I, particularly, prefer the second form. But while I'm the only one to code my program, I know that, but some else could not know, and could lead to 2 `malloc`, and leak of memory.

So, my question is: What's the best practice for this?

Comment: malloc inside or outside doesn't matter, just make sure to free the allocated memory that's it

Comment: its depends on situation too!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Allocating memory in the caller is more flexible, because it allows the caller to use static or automatic storage instead of dynamic allocation, and eliminates the need to handle the case of allocation failure in the callee. On the other hand, having the caller provide the storage requires the caller to know the size in advance. If the size is compiled into the caller as a constant and the callee is in a library that's later updated to use a larger structure, things will break horribly. You can avoid this, of course, by providing a second function (or external variable in the library) for retrieving the necessary size.

When in doubt, you can always make two functions:

1. The main function that uses caller-provided storage.
2. A wrapper function which allocates the right amount of storage, calls the function in #1 using it, and returns the pointer to the caller.

Then the caller is free to choose whichever method is more appropriate for the particular usage case.

Answer (score 8):

I personally strongly favor your first proposition (whenever it is possible) for orthogonality. Take the following example:

```
extern void bar(int *p, int n);

void foo(int n)
{

   int *p = malloc(n * sizeof *p);

   // fill array object
   bar(p, n);

   // work with array elements

   /* ... */

   // array no longer needed, free object
   free(p);
}
```

This is orthogonal. `malloc` and `free` are called in the same lexical scope which is clean and readable. Another advantage is you can pass to `bar` function an array with a different storage duration for example an array with automatic or static storage duration. You let `bar` function focus only on the work it has do and let another function manage the array allocation.

Note that this is also how all Standard C functions work: they never *appear* to call `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

The criteria I'd use for deciding are:

- If the code outside the called function can know how much memory to allocate, then it is better to have the calling code allocate the memory.
- If the code outside the called function cannot know how much memory to allocate, then the called function must do the memory allocation.  It is likely then that there will be a second function available to release the memory returned by the first function (the 'called' function), unless it is just a single `free()` that's needed.  The function documentation should make this clear.

For example, if the called function is reading a complete tree structure from a file, the function will have to allocate the memory.  But, there will also be a companion function for releasing the memory (since the called code knows how to do it and the calling code shouldn't need to know).

On the other hand, if the called function is reading a simple list of integer and floating point values into a fixed size structure, it is far better to make the calling function allocate the memory.  Note that I skipped 'strings'!  If the strings are of a fixed size in the structure, then the calling function can do the allocation, but if the strings are of variable size, then probably the called function does the allocation.

The Standard C Library has functions like [`fgets()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) which expect the calling code to allocate the memory to be used.  The calling sequence tells `fgets()` how much space is available.  You run into problems if you didn't provide enough memory.  (The problem with `fgets()` is that you may only get the start of a line of text, not the whole line of text.)

The POSIX 2008 Library provides [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) which will allocate enough space for the line.

The [`asprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) and related functions (see [TR24731-2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/projects#24731-2)) allocate memory as required.  The [`snprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html) function does not — it is told how much space there is available, it uses no more than that, and says how much it really needed, and it is up to you to note if you didn't provide enough space and do something about it (allocate more space and try again, or blithely ignore the truncated value and continue as if nothing went wrong).

Answer (score 1):

The principal of information hiding suggests that it allocating memory is best done within a function.

If you look at how ***stdio.h*** works:

```
FILE *myFile;

myFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");

if (!myFile) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error opening input.txt for reading.\n");
  // other exit handling close
}
else {
  // code to read from file
  fclose(myFile);
}
```

the library call allocates memory that holds information about the file you are working with, and it returns a pointer to that structure. The caller is responsible for later on freeing that memory (with a call to *fclose*).

This pattern is repeated throughout the Standard C library.

There are at least two disadvantages to requiring the caller to allocate and free memory:

1. Extra code would be required on the calling side.
2. The calling code would need to be recompiled (at a minimum) or changed if the size of structure being allocated ever changed.